# Calculate UDF once

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql, uuid

I want to have a UUID column in a pyspark dataframe that is calculated only once, so that I can select the column in a different dataframe and have the UUIDs be the same. However, the UDF for the UUID column is recalculated when I select the column.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
>>> uuid_udf = udf(lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), StringType())
>>> a = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2]], ['col1', 'col2'])
>>> a = a.withColumn('id', uuid_udf())
>>> a.collect()
[Row(col1=1, col2=2, id='5ac8f818-e2d8-4c50-bae2-0ced7d72ef4f')]
>>> b = a.select('id')
>>> b.collect()
[Row(id='12ec9913-21e1-47bd-9c59-6ddbe2365247')]  # Wanted this to be the same ID as above
```

**Possible workaround: rand()**

A possible workaround might be to use pyspark.sql.functions.rand() as my source of randomness. However, there are two problems:

1) I'd like to have letters, not just numbers, in the UUID, so that it doesn't need to be quite as long

2) Though it technically works, it produces ugly UUIDs:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, round
>>> a = a.withColumn('id', round(rand() * 10e16))
>>> a.collect()
[Row(col1=1, col2=2, id=7.34745165108606e+16)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spark built-in [`uuid`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#uuid) function instead:

```
a = a.withColumn('id', expr("uuid()"))
b = a.select('id')

b.collect()
[Row(id='da301bea-4927-4b6b-a1cf-518dea8705c4')]

a.collect()
[Row(col1=1, col2=2, id='da301bea-4927-4b6b-a1cf-518dea8705c4')]
```

Comment: I didn't know this one. Good to know. Works with every version ?

Comment: built-in SQL function `uuid` appeared in 2.3.0 release ([see JIRA SPARK-20910](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20910))

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your UUID keeps changing is because your dataframe is computed again and again after each action.

To stabilize your result, you can just use `persist` or `cache` (depending on the size of your dataframe).

```py
df.persist()

df.show()                                                                                          
+---+--------------------+
| id|                uuid|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|e3db115b-6b6a-424...|
+---+--------------------+


b = df.select("uuid")                                                                              

b.show()                                                                                           
+--------------------+
|                uuid|
+--------------------+
|e3db115b-6b6a-424...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Great answer. I accepted the other one because it does exactly what I need, but this is good to know.