# Fill null values with new elements in pyspark df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find a way to join two df that have a certain `colName` common amongst them, and fill the `null` values with new values by using a `func()`

I have two DFs

DF1:

```
+---------------+                                                               
|        colName|
+---------------+
|              a|
|              b|
|              c|
|              d|
+---------------+
```

and DF2:

```
+-------+-------------+
|colName|         uuid|
+-------+-------------+
|      a|            1|
|      b|            2|
+-------+-------------+
```

After using a specific pyspark funciton like `DF1.join(DF2, where(DF1.colName == DF2.colName))` or `df.merge()` I'd like to obtain a df with the following values

DF1 + DF2:

```
+-------+-------------+
|colName|         uuid|
+-------+-------------+
|      a|            1|
|      b|            2|
|      c|         null|
|      d|         null|
+-------+-------------+
```

and then using a `func()`:

```
def func():
    doSomethin(DF1+DF2)
```

The following result is expected:

```
+-------+-------------+
|colName|         uuid|
+-------+-------------+
|      a|            1|
|      b|            2|
|      c|            3|
|      d|            4|
+-------+-------------+
```

As you can see, `DF1` just has `colName`, whereas `DF2` has `uuid` associated. So `func()` will actually generate a uuid and fill distinct `colName` with distinct `uuid`. Any approach towards this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate UDF once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843216/calculate-udf-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `uuid` function simply.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1.join(df2, ['colName'], 'left') \
   .withColumn('uuid', f.coalesce(f.col('uuid'), f.expr('uuid()'))) \
   .show(10, False)

+-------+------------------------------------+
|colName|uuid                                |
+-------+------------------------------------+
|a      |1                                   |
|b      |2                                   |
|c      |ad037b01-4be8-40f2-99fc-b7589b2c648c|
|d      |e59c9315-b626-4dcf-a80a-e16f08f19a96|
+-------+------------------------------------+
```